# Cannot access samba share from one PC but from others, even after reinstalling the PC

Tags: windows-10, networking, samba

I have a samba share running on a raspberry pi 4. I can access it from one Desktop-PC (Win10) and one laptop (Win11). But I cannot access it from my ASUS VivoBook S (Win10) for some reason. All I get is error 0x80004005. However, I can ping the pi and reache it via SSH or remote desktop. I can also access shared folders on other computers.

I tried every possible solution that I could possibly find on the internet. Finally, I even reinstalled that laptop and once again enabled SMBv1, without luck.

Comment: Is the one that doesn't connect fully updated (as it should be)?

Answer (score 1):

Check the SMB configuration on the Raspberry Pi aswell as the network configuration and name resolution on the notebook. Make sure those are properly configured.

This [Blog](https://dannyda.com/2021/12/19/how-to-fix-windows-accessing-windows-share-samba-smb-share-error-network-error-cannot-access-share-address-0x80004005/) mentions that

> By default, Windows 10 / Windows Server 2016/2019/2022 does not allow insecure guest logon to an SMB server, which means accessing a SMB share without password is not allow, hence we will get the network error 0x80004005. To override this security restriction, we can use Gorup Policy Editor.

and goes through a fix. Other than that you could refer to the [Samba Wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_File_Serving) on troubleshooting shares.

It might also be helpful to include the SMB configuration from the Raspberry Pi's smb.conf file and the network configuration on the ASUS VivoBook S in the question, as this could provide more insight into the problem and allow for more targeted troubleshooting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).