# Error 0x8007003B on SMB Shares when "Guests allowed" set

Tags: networking, network-shares, samba

When I enable the option "Guests allowed" for any SMB/CIFS share on my OMV 6.1.3-1 server, Windows 10 and 11 report error 0x8007003B "Unexpected Network Error", when copying file to or from the share.

On Windows, the credentials for a valid OpenMediaVault user are stored and personal or team shares work perfectly fine. Just the public shares with additional guest access are generating this error.

I don't know this problem from my experience with Debian Samba, is there something I am missing here?

Comment: @Cellon: Did you try solution provided in this question: [Cannot access samba share from one PC but from others, even after reinstalling the PC](https://superuser.com/q/1759721/1266966)? Seems like you need to use **Group Policy Editor** to override restrictions for access the guest users.

Comment: @Jackdaw Well, no. That is a totally different case.